# Who's states would change first and how?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle, thought-experiment, quantum-teleportation, quantum-states

If someone's quantum states were copied a few miles away and a group of particles there were changed to the same states(except position), thus a copy of that person would form a few miles away. If I'm wrong correct me, both groups of particles would still exist at the same time. So lets say we then simultaneously change their positions so they both go to the same position at the same time, therefore the PEP would force them to change states, so which one would change and how?

Comment: Just as an aside, it'd be practically impossible to copy all of someone's quantum states...

Comment: And you would likely have to kill them first, to measure **everything** about them.

Comment: how would you go about doing all this?

Comment: It's theoretical, I'll add the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I did some research and found a video that answers my question. According to the No Cloning rule, all the information and energy of the original person would need to be extracted but to do so the person would be destroyed. This is not because of the PEP. Then you would be broken down and turned into energy, after that the energy would be used to reassemble you somewhere else.

[Video link: minutephysics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAaHHGHuy1c)

Comment: You should probably link to the video.